React routing, when clicking the link the right URL is visited but the whole site is white
I'm trying to build a KanBan-board. I have a Board Component at localhost/ and there I can see all three columns. In the headline of the first column for example, I have a link which leads to localhost/todo. And when I click it the whole site is white. Even though my Column Component is exactly the same in App.jsx as in Board.jsx. Why is that?
function App() {
  
  return (
    <DataProvider>
      <DataContext.Consumer>
        {({ columns }) => (
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Board />} />
            {console.log(columns)}
            <Route
              path={`${columns.id}`}
              element={<Columns columnId={columns.id} title={columns.title} />}
            />
          </Routes>
        )}
      </DataContext.Consumer>
    </DataProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

And this is my Board Component
const Board = () => {
  const { columns } = useContext(DataContext);

  console.log(columns);
  return (
    <main>
      {columns.map((column, index) => (
        <Columns key={index} id={column.id} title={column.title} />
      ))}
    </main>
  );
};

export default Board;

The column itself looks like this:
const Columns = ({ id, title }) => {
  const { tasks, selectedTask} = useContext(DataContext);

  // Filtrera tasks baserat på kolumnens ID
  const filteredTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.column === id);

  return (
    <section id="column">
      <h2 className="headerColumn">
        <Link
          style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
          id="linkColumn"
          to={`/${id}`}
        >
          {title}
        </Link>
      </h2>
      {filteredTasks.map((task, index) => (
        <div key={index} >
          <Card task={task} />
        </div>
      ))}
      {selectedTask && <CardPopUp />}
      {id === "todo" && (
        <div className="inputHolder">
          <AddTask />
        </div>
      )}
    </section>
  );
};

export default Columns;


If someone has any idea please help.

Any errors in the console? And can you show us the value that's being provided in DataProvider?

No errors at all

{
id: "todo",
title: "To Do",
},
{
id: "doing",
title: "Doing",
},
{
id: "done",
title: "Done",
},
this is the ''columns'' thats being provided @NicholasTower

columns is an array of those? Or just a single one? If it's an array, arrays don't have an id property, which means path={\${columns.id}`}ispath="undefined"`

yeah it's an array in DataContext. const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
{
id: "todo",
title: "To Do",
},
{
id: "doing",
title: "Doing",
},
{
id: "done",
title: "Done",
},
]);
But how do i get to the id then? In the Columns component, i get the Id and Title from const { columns } = useContext(DataContext); because in the Board where the columns are mapped out, i've put props for the Columns component like this:

@NicholasTower

 <Route
  path={`${columns.id}`}
  element={<Columns columnId={columns.id} title={columns.title} />}
/>

Since columns is an array, columns.id is undefined. As a result, this would only show if the url was "localhost/undefined", and even then, it would be passing in an undefined id and title.
I think what you meant to do was have a route parameter, which you do with a : followed by whatever you want to name the parameter:
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Board />} />
  <Route
    path="/:columnId"
    element={/* we'll get to this */}
  />
</Routes>

That will match if there's a slash followed by any string. To figure out what string the url is currently set to, you can use the useParams hook. If you want to keep your Columns component the way it is (receiving data via props), then you could make a new component. That component calls the appropriate hooks, figures out the column, then passes it in to the <Columns> component:
const ColumnPage = () => {
  const { columnId } = useParams();
  const { columns } = useContext(DataContext);
  const column = columns.find(column => column.id === columnId);

  return <Columns id={column.id} title={column.title} />
}
// elsewhere:
<Route
  path="/:columnId"
  element={<ColumnPage />}
/>

